# Formulário de pedidos com Python e Django

Tags: html5, python, aplicação-web, django

Estou iniciando meus estudos com Python e Django.  Após criar vários CRUDS simples, tentei criar um formulário mais complexo utilizando varias classes, porém não tive sucesso.

Eu quero criar uma tela para digitação de pedidos com as informações do cliente (o cliente poder ser cadastrado junto com o pedido), uma lista com os vendedores e adicionar os produtos.  Para adicionar os produtos penso em criar uma janela modal que consulte os produtos ou um campo com autocomplete no próprio formulário com um botão adicionar.

Duvidas:

- É uma boa prática criar formulários manuais e persistir os dados manualmente?
- Qual a melhor forma de se criar um formulário que possua informações de vários modelos (Pedido, ItemPedido, Produto e Vendedor)?

Estou usando Python 3.5, Django 1.10 no Linux.

Desde já agradeço pela ajuda.

Comment: Olá - sua pergunta não foi muito clara. Sugiro dar uma lida na documentação da classe `Forms` do Django https://docs.djangoproject.com/pt-br/1.10/ref/forms/api/

Comment: Leonardo, obrigado pelo retorno.  Editei a minha pergunta, só queria o caminho que devo seguir para criar um formulário mais complexo.  Eu já tinha navegado no link que você enviou, porém qual é a melhor opção?  Obrigado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sugiro que você utilize a [API de `Forms` do Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/pt-br/1.10/ref/forms/api/).

Não vou entrar no mérito de como construir um formulário porque não me parece o escopo da pergunta, portanto, vou apenas enfatizar alguns dos benefícios que vemos:

**1. Validadores para o formulário e campos**

Deixe que o Django tome conta das validações dos tipos de dados pra você baseado no tipo do campo escolhido no `Model`.

**2. Diversas opções de formatações**

Você pode utilizar dos métodos para exibir o `form` como lista ou texto, além de customizar as [`template tags`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/custom-template-tags/) para personalizar ainda mais seu estilo. Você pode, ainda, iterar campo a campo pra customizar a sua exibição dentro do template, como por exemplo:

**index.html**

```
<html>
<head><title>Meu site</title></head>
<body>
<h1>Aqui vai o meu formulário:</h1>
{% for field in form %}
    <p style="color:red">Campo em vermelho num parágrafo com filter: {{ field|meu_filter_personalizado }}</p>
{% endfor %}
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: A ideia do formulário manual, já descartei.  Com relação ao segundo item, a sua sugestão seria criar um form para cada model, eu consigo alterar o layout ou só utilizar {{ form.as_table }} ou {{ form.as_p }}?   Ainda estou confuso com relação ao form padrão e o customizado (template).  Obrigado pelo retorno.

Comment: Sim, utilizar um `form` por `model`. Tem várias formas de customizar os campos, podendo utilizar template tags/filters (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/custom-template-tags/) ou mesmo iterando campo a campo e printando no HTML da forma que quiser (https://docs.djangoproject.com/pt-br/1.10/ref/forms/api/#accessing-the-fields-from-the-form)

Comment: Obrigado Leonardo.  Vou estudar os links que você enviou.  Caso tenha alguma dúvida, eu retorno.

Comment: Leonardo, estudei os dois links.  No custom-template-tags, eu consigo criar "funções" do tipo converter uma string para minuscula ou maiúscula...  Ok, são uteis.

Comment: Nas Apis forms, já consegui entender como unir várias classes em uma única utilizando herança multipla.  Perfeito, fiz os exemplos no shell, entendi o conceito de forms bound e unbound, maravilha.  Agora a dúvida principal seria com relação ao posicionamento dos campos no html que é gerado automaticamente.  Não consegui entender onde posso posicionar meus campos no formaulario.  Ex.:  Na primeira linha quero que sejam exibidas as informações nome do cliente e email, na segunda endereço, numero, bairro...  Me desculpe se a minha pergunta é obvia, mas estou inciando...

Comment: Atualizei a resposta com uma maneira de iterar campo a campo para customização máxima. Se quiser escolher um `field` em específico, pode adicionar um `if` que compare se o campo tem o nome que você procura pra customizar

Comment: Eu poderia fazer referencia direta aos fields do form? Remover o for e inserir os fields em divs?  Assim eu conseguiria posicionar cada field na página.  Mais uma vez, agradeço pela sua grande boa vontade e ajuda.  Obrigado.  Ex.: <div>{{form.name}}</div><div>{{form.endereco}}</div>

Comment: Leonardo, acho que compliquei algo que era muito simples.  Consegui utilizar os fields um a um na página sem o for.  Muito obrigado pelas suas orientações.  Caso tenha alguma dúvida, eu retorno.

Comment: Disponha! Se a resposta respondeu a sua pergunta, por favor, lembre-se de aceitá-la no check acima. Se teve algo nos comentários que lhe foi útil e quiser editar a minha resposta para adicionar, melhor ainda. :)